# piping hot java --- some strange behavior when processing stdin with java from bash

Tags: java, bash, java.util.scanner, stdin

Suppose I have the following (silly) java program which cycles back and forth between `main` and `aux`, whenever a `y` is typed:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Minimal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("in main...");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String s;
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {

            s = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(s);
            if(s.equals("y")) {
                aux();
                System.out.println("in main...");
            }       
        }
    }

    public static void aux() {

        System.out.println("in aux...");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String s;
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {

            s = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(s);
            if(s.equals("y")) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But then, when I run

```
$ javac Minimal.java
$ printf "y\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\n" | java Minimal
```

in bash, I get a different answer than when running

```
$ java Minimal
```

and typing (interactively) `y` followed by `<ENTER>` --- seemingly equivalent to what was fed in automatically above with `printf`.  Any ideas?

Comment: You never print `in main...` once you return from `aux`.

Comment: It has nothing to with "different way of reading from stdin" and everything to do with your input. Java has no way to differentiate input from a user or from another process using piped standard input. That is the "standardized" part of standard input.

Comment: thanks --- and so the question is why a sequence of `y` followed by `<ENTER>` *is* different than `printf "y\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny..."`

Comment: Now edit your question and explain **how** it is different. A screenshot or example session with actual output would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is because of buffering.  `Scanner` buffers its input, so it may consume more than one line at a time from `System.in`.  When you use `printf`, the data is available immediately so it is all consumed by the `Scanner` instance in `main()`.  As a result, there is no more data available for the `Scanner` created in each call to `aux()` to read.

When you run the program interactively, the terminal sends the data line by line as you enter it, so there isn't any extra data available to get buffered at each read.

To avoid this problem, don't create more than one instance of `Scanner` for the same `InputStream`.